# И как всегда - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"И(,) как всегда, получила ответы на многие вопросы".

Отмечу при этом, что предложение стоит в начале абзаца. Поэтому оно совсем не смотрелось бы, если выбросить "как всегда".

Может ли здесь не стоять запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь И формально может быть не только союзом, но и усилительной частицей. Поэтому "де-юре" запятую можно и ставить, и опустить.  Вариантов обоснования предостаточно.

Но! Исходя из того, что по мнению автора без вводного слова предложения не смотрится полагаю, что И здесь по мнению автора (пусть даже он сам это не может сформулировать) все-таки союз, причем такой, который относится именно к части "[И] как всегда", а не "[И] получила...". Запятой не надо. 
Вот если бы "смотрелась" я бы как раз подумал о запятых.

Возможно, логика не совсем академическая, но в данном случае, думаю, что вполне допустимая.

А разбивку на абзацы явно стоит пересмотреть, если, конечно, существующая не преследует цели создания этакой эпатажности.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь **особый случай**: предложение ***неполное***, его смысл становится понятным только из предыдущего (жаль, что Вы его не приводите). 
Запятая перед вводным предложением (выражением) КАК ВСЕГДА **нужна**, несмотря на то что союз стоит в начале предложения. 
Роль союза И в этом предложении не только присоединительная. Он также соединяет сказуемые предыдущего и нашего предложений. Ср.: ***[Я пришла на конференцию] И, как всегда, получила ответы на многие вопросы.*** Выражение КАК ВСЕГДА легко изымается из контекста. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Все-таки нахождение  предложения  в начале абзаца говорит о том, что союз И соединяет не два предложения, это союз текстовый, он соединяет абзацы. Если предложение действтительно подобно Вашему, то запятая нужна, но тогда не нужен абзац.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что до этого говорилось о другом. 
Само предложение звучит точнее так: "И(,) как всегда, получила ответы на многие вопросы в рубрике "Вопрос - ответ"

Comment: Ребята, не буду спорить, но я бы запятую точно поставила.
Иногда (при интонационном выделении вводных слов или вводных предложений, при их включении в текст посредством подчинительного союза) после присоединительного союза запятая перед вводной конструкцией ставится:...И, как водится, вспоминали только одно хорошее (Крым.)(http://lib.rus.ec/b/118184/read)

Comment: EkaterinaKas.., но вопрос-то был "Может ли здесь не стоять запятая?" .При всех вариантах МОЖЕТ, союз И в начале предложения - выразительное средство: при отсутствии запятой исполняет роль частицы,  усиливает  КАК ВСЕГДА .

Comment: Запятая перед союзом КАК ставится в трех случаях:
1. Если этот союз входит в обороты, близкие по роли в предложении к вводным словам, например: КАК ПРАВИЛО, КАК ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ, КАК СЛЕДСТВИЕ, КАК ВСЕГДА, КАК СЕЙЧАС, КАК НАРОЧНО, КАК НАПРИМЕР, КАК ТЕПЕРЬ: Утром, как нарочно, начался дождь;
2. Если этот союз соединяет части сложноподчиненного предложения, например: Мы долго смотрели, как тлеют угли костра;
3. Если в предложении есть обстоятельство, выраженное сравнительным оборотом, который начинается с союза КАК
(http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

Comment: Здесь нет И.

Answer (score 2):

Вводное слово обычно не отделяется знаком препинания от присоединительного союза, стоящего в начале предложения.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/

Answer (score 0):

***Запятая тут не нужна) Если даже подумать логически,то запятая там вообще не ставится***

Comment: Минус -мой. Бездоказательно.

Answer (score 0):

Выделяется не "и", а вводное слово "как всегда".